# Nightwatch perform() not method after expect

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, nightwatch.js

So I believe after looking through the documentation that this should work correctly, but I would like to have something run one the expect has finished, however currently it not seem to be working.

**Working**

```
browser
  .url('https://www.google.co.uk/?')
  .expect.element('.Google Search').value.to.contain('Dashboard')
  .perform(function() {
    console.log('elementValue');
  })
```

**Broken**

```
browser
  .url('https://www.google.co.uk/?')
  .expect.element('.Google Search').value.to.contain('Dashboard')
  .perform(function() {
    console.log('elementValue');
  })


Error while running perform command: browser.moveToElement(...).doubleClick(...).setValue(...).click(...).expect.element(...).text.to.contain(...).perform is not a function
```

Comment: The code from your post doesn't match the description from the error.

Comment: I cut out many of the needless api's methods :)

Comment: the code which is supposed to be broken in your post is  exactly the same as the one you tagged as working.

Comment: lol yes indeed, I will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.expect` you break the Nightwatch command chain and start Expect.js chain so after you call `.expect.element('.Google Search')` you get Expect.js object and not Nightwatch `browser` object.

What you need is to simply start another chain:

```
browser
  .url('https://www.google.co.uk/?')
  .expect.element('.Google Search').value.to.contain('Dashboard');

browser
  .perform(function() {
    console.log('elementValue');
  });
```